# Sometimes saveInBackground's callback never get called

Tags: android, callback, parse-platform

I'm writing a chat application on Android using the Parse SDK (1.5.1) in which i use obj.saveInBackground(SaveCallback) to create a new chat message on the cloud. The problem is that sometimes the SaveCallback never get called (I put a log inside the callback and that log never be printed out). 
This usually occurs when i continuously send out about 20-30 chat messages, for each message, i use saveInBackground to create it, but the callback just be called for the first messages (for example, it was ok to create message 1 to 30, but for message 30-40, the callbacks were not called and they couldn't be created).

It seems that when the problem occurs, all the "ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-xx" threads are in the Wait status (maybe they are waiting for results sent back from server?). 
Please take a look at the [application's threads snapshot when this problem occurs.](http://s1174.photobucket.com/user/hcmwae8/media/threads_zps56fde9c3.png.html)

Is there anyone encountered a similar problem before? Could you please give me advices how to deal with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem in case of files, so I used recursion function. may be you have to call recursion method of saving messages until all messages are saved to parse...

Comment: Thank you Naveed, you meant I should call saveInBackground repeatedly until the objects are saved to parse, right? I'll give it a try then. By the way, do you have any idea why this happens? is it a server-side problem or parse sdk's problem?... I read about "request limit" from https://parse.com/plans/faq/, but since there wasn't any RequestLimitExceeded logged, i guess this is not because the number of requests has exceeded the limit...

Comment: yes you have to call again and again, and I don not know why this is happening.